# xml2json install Error Can't find Python executable you can set the PYTHON env variable

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have some problems while installing xml2json with NPM.

My Development Environment is like this.

OS : Windows 10 Pro 64bit
IDE : Visual Studio Code
Node Version : 8.10.0

Nowadays I do node projects. But I cannot install xml2json. In npmjs.com

It can install with this command

```
$ npm install xml2json
```

But command said it cannot be installed. The error message is like this.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM2oB.png)

```
C:\Users\super\Downloads\project\data\myapp>npm install xml2json

> node-expat@2.3.16 install C:\Users\super\Downloads\project\data\myapp\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\super\Downloads\project\data\myapp\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)                                              fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\super\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\super\Downloads\project\data\myapp\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.16 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-31T15_33_12_196Z-debug.log
```

I already install python and added it to path but it's still not working. and I tired to solve this problem with the error message but nothing can give me a solution.

I already tried to node-gyp rebuild and other methods.

Comment: Do you have this same problem with other packages?

Comment: @JM-AGMS No, I don't have any problems when I installed other packages. Only the xml2json package is problem.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/nfroidure/ttf2woff2/issues/28 Different NPM but the resolution could be the same.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thank you. This link helps me a lot. I solved the problem. It said I have to install python 2.x. 3.x version will not working, and then these solutions are working. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Might Help if someone else ever face this problem,

- (Optional) Install Python [Download From Here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
- Run the following command as Administrator in windows Terminal 
  `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

  (This will Install Windows Build Tools and also Install Python 2.7)

  [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64p9K.png)
- Install node-gyp globally as admin using the following command:
  `npm install node-gyp`

That’s it! After the installation is complete, close and re-run (normally) the terminal window and proceed by installing the problematic package again, which should run successfully.

You can Check [this](https://catalin.me/how-to-fix-node-js-gyp-err-cant-find-python-executable-python-on-windows/) Original Post if you want.